Stop MySQL Workbench from deleting password on connection failure
I use MySQL Workbench behind VPN to connect to a database that allows connections only from whitelisted IP addresses. If the VPN connection drops and my IP changes, before I am able to reconnect and get the IP back, MySQL Workbench manages to send some kind of keepalive request to the database server, which of course gets rejected. Then Workbench thinks my credentials are no longer good, and deletes the stored database password.
I want to stop this behaviour because the password is fine, and the database server lets me in as soon as I restore the IP address it allows and, well, go get the password and re-save it, which is an inconvenience.
Is there an easy way to stop this?
MySQL Workbench 8.0.28 CE on a Mac, passwords are stored to macOS Keychain / iCloud.

only if you rewrite workbench. your system looks somewhat off start a vpn at the mysql site and connct directly, then your ip really doesn't matter
